# Hinata's & her children's family name by the end of Naruto

Tags: naruto

What is Hyuuga Hinata's family name after she married Naruto? Is it still Hyuuga, or has it changed to Uzumaki? And what about their children? Are their surnames Uzumaki or Hyuuga?

Please also post the proof of them being called with their family name and not just quoting their name in Wikia, as the Wikia page currently doesn't have the proof of them being called with their family name (by 29-04-2015 4:20 PM GMT+7 time).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm gonna have to say that Hinata's surname will remain as it is. Because, if we take the case of two other couples, who were from different clans and had offsprings, we can see that wives' surname remains as it is. Examples are:

1. Minato Namikaze and Kushina Uzumaki
2. Asuma Sarutobi and Kurenai Yūhi

In both cases, even after their marriage, their surnames were kept the same. So this leads me to believe that Hinata will retain her surname as Hyuuga.

Taking the same examples for the case of the offsprings,

1. Naruto
2. Mirai Sarutobi

Mirai's case, she retains her father's surname. While Naruto's official surname is Uzumaki. But the Uzumaki surname was given to him because it was a means to protect him and his identity (from enemies). I think there was a chapter which discussed that incident. Therefore, his original surname was Namikaze.

From these examples, I think its safe to say that the child recieves the surname of the male parent. Which means the names will be Boruto Uzumaki and Himawari Uzumaki.

---

**Update:** (credits to @AyaseEri)

As for physical evidence, the 8th official guidebook, [**Zai no Sho**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Zai_no_Sho) (released Aug 7th 2015) confirms that Boruto and Himawari have their surname as Uzumaki:

> Boruto Uzumaki (page 26)
>
> Himawari Uzumaki (page 31)

But it seems my logic with the wife's surname being preserved is faulty. As in Zai no Sho, Hinata's surname is not Hyuga, but **Uzumaki** (page 31). Therefore, her official name after marriage has become Hinata Uzumaki.

Comment: Asuma & Kurenai never got married.

Comment: @MaskedMan The marriage has been confirmed in [Retsu no Sho](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Retsu_no_Sho)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. I always thought Asuma died before they could get married. Thanks for that info. :)

Comment: @EroSɘnnin You can update the physical evidence now, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Kurenai changed her name after her and Asuma married. I believe you can find the info in Retsu no Sho like Ero Sennin said. Pg 32, if I recall.

Further expanding on this, Sakura takes Sasuke's name. I do not recall, however, if Temari ever got a last name from marrying Shikamaru. And I believe the case with Sai is unique due to Sai being male with no name. Would he then take the Yamanaka name?

As for Naruto's birth name; while I don't doubt that his surname was chosen as Uzumaki to prevent people from coming after him, I have doubts that his birth surname would've been Namikaze as the Uzumaki clan is a prestigious clan in Konoha, therefore an explanation as to how/why Hinata bore the Uzumaki name rather than the Hyuuga name. (That and personal preference by Hinata.)

In feudal Japan (estimated time Naruto takes place, apart from certain advances in technology, such as fridges and headsets), clan names were an important thing and if you were a male marrying into a prestigious clan, unless you yourself came from an equal or greater clan, you bore that clan's surname instead of your wife bearing yours. And Minato wasn't from a prestigious clan himself, though he personally was prestigious enough to retain his own name.

Comment: Hi and welcome. The preferred Stack Exchange way to ‘reply to an existing answer’ is generally by posting a correct stand-alone answer. If the issues are minor (e.g. somebody obviously just got two characters mixed up), you can also suggest an [edit] (that link will lead you to editing your own post, but under every post there is an edit link) which will be reviewed by the community. Note that SE explicitly endorses multiple different answers to questions so the best answers can get voted up. Also, feel free to take a [tour] of the site.

Comment: Well, I was trying to reply to Ero Sennin's answer specifically, but couldn't figure out how. I do believe that adding more comments onto their answer has been disabled for whatever reason, though. Thanks for the information, though!

Comment: @HadakaKyoujin Once you have earned 50 reputation (which is equivalent to 5 upvotes on answers), you will be able to [post comments on other people's posts](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ah. Thank you, Senshin. That would explain it, then.